# Prealoder ao solicitar dowload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou fazendo um retorno de um pdf apartir de uma Custom `ActionResult`

```
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=teste.pdf");
```

E gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer um `preloader` enquanto o servidor processa este `download`

[Edit]

Conforme solicitado, o código do link que faço o pedido de download

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Print", "Report", new { id = 20 }, new AjaxOptions { 
        Confirm="Are you cure?",
        HttpMethod="GET",
        LoadingElementId="divLoading"
    })
```

Comment: Você se refere a algo [assim?](http://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL) Se for, avise que formulo a resposta.

Comment: @Randrade, não entendi, este é um preloader em css/js

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que seria o `preloader` que você se refere então?

Comment: @Randrade olá, então, o link que você me enviou é um preloader em css/js...mas lendo a minha pergunta, o preloader deve ter sincronia com o processamento do server, ou seja, quando ele finalizar o processo e retornar o file para download, o preloader se "fecha"

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. Só queria saber se o `preloader` que você se referiu era isso mesmo. Poste como você chama a `action` para download, que amanhã eu posto uma resposta para você, estou no celular agora.

Comment: ah sim...é isso mesmo que eu quis dizer com preloader, então, é uma custom actionresult, ela faz todo processamento e retorna o response que eu colei ali

Comment: Você chama a **action** por um link normal, ou utiliza `ajax` ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 0):

Suponhamos que você já possui o `preloader` pronto (html, css, js) e precise apenas chamar e ocultar o mesmo no momento do `download`. Caso não possua, [aqui tem um exemplo.](http://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL)

Você pode utilizar `ajax` para chamar sua **ActionResult** e chamar o seu `preloader ao mesmo tempo.`

```
<script>
    $(".downloadAnexo").click(function () {
        $("#divPreloader").fadeIn();//Chama o preloader
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFile")?id=' + 1,//Sua ActionResult
            type: 'GET',
            success: function () {
                $("#divPreloader").hide();//Esconde o preloader em caso de sucesso
            }, error: function () {
                $("#divPreloader").hide();//Esconde o preloader em caso de erro
            }  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Veja um exemplo no [dotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pTcJma)

### Edit

Usando o [Ajax.ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=VS.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) você possui dois as opções **OnBegin** e **OnComplete**. Basta você chamar as funções para mostrar e esconder o `preloader`. Ficaria assim:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Print", "Index", new { id = 20 }, new AjaxOptions
{
    Confirm = "Are you cure?",
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    LoadingElementId = "divLoading",
      OnBegin = "onAjaxBegin",//Chamo a função onAjaxBegin
    OnComplete = "onAjaxComplete"//Quando completar, chamo a função onAjaxComplete
})
```

E você cria as funções para fazer o que deseja:

```
<script>
   function onAjaxBegin() {
            $('#divPreloader').fadeIn();
        }

        function onAjaxComplete() {
            $('#divPreloader').hide();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Essa sua opção, é quando o servidor retorna um arquivo já fiisico ou seja que há um caminho para o arquivo

Comment: E como você faz para chamar a `ActionResult` então?

Comment: Eu uso Ajax.ActionLink

Comment: Poderia adicionar o código em sua pergunta?

Comment: Veja se a adição lhe ajudou.

Comment: o link não faz o download....não há como